# How to access a variable from another class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 classes (I attached the code below). I need to access a variable that is in the second class (DropdownWidget class) so that I can make a boolean condition in the first class. Is the variable you want to get called `String? selectedValue`. How to get access to it correctly? Thank you in advance.

**class 1**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: size.height,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/background/main_background.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),
      child: _child(size, context),
    );
  }
```

**class 2 from here you need to get the variable**

```
class DropdownWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  List<String> items;
  SvgPicture? icon;
  double width;

  DropdownWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.items,
    required this.icon,
    required this.width,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropdownWidget> createState() => _DropdownWidgetState();
}

class _DropdownWidgetState extends State<DropdownWidget> {
  String? selectedValue;
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: widget.width,
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2(
          items: widget.items
              .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: item,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border(
                          bottom: BorderSide(
                            color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.1),
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: You need some kind of state management in your app. I suggest you start reading at https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: You can pass a function to the other `Class` as a sort of callback. This will allow you to modify the other data and possibly `setState` to make those changes visible to whichever `Class` is the current view.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd say you should pass it down from your main widget to the `DropdownWidget`, but you want to change it. For maximum flexibility, I'd opt for using the `provider` package with the `ChangeNotifierProvider`: https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html

That may be too much effort though, and if your `DropdownWidget` lives directly below the main Widget you want to call it from, you could simply use a callback function, to update the corresponding state variable in the main widget when you update the `DropdownWidget`.